# Creating an SQL Server Sandbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, sandbox

There are some features in our LOB application that allow users to define their own queries to retrieve data for reports and listings within the app. The problem that we are encountering is that sometimes these queries they have written a really heavy (and sometimes erroneous) and cause massive load on the server.

Removing these features is out of the question but Im wanting to know if there is a way to create some type of sandbox within SQL server so that the queries that they execute are only allotted a certain amount of resources to execute therefore not giving them the chance to cause any damage to anyone else using the system. Any ideas?

Comment: "that allow users to define their own queries to retrieve data for reports and listings within the app" - there's your first mistake!! Why? because "... sometimes these queries they have written a really heavy (and sometimes erroneous) " Aside from the fact that you have to be careful about SQL injection and your users are free to write poor queries (and possibly incorrect), lookup 'resource governor'.

Comment: It sounds like you want to look at Resource Governor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Resource governor has been mentioned in the comments above already. One other solution I can think of is using *SQL Server High Availability Groups*.

At the last place I worked had this kind of set up. There is a primary server which takes in all the transactions that write stuff to the database, with a secondary in case the primary fails. Added to this we also had read-only replicas added to the availability group.

The main purpose of this is in the event that your main server goes down you are automatically transferred to another replica. When you connect your application to the database, you connect it to the Availability Group rather than a specific server. Then if a server goes down you are automatically transferred to a secondary server instead. However, it can also be used to optimise application functionality that just needs read-only access by taking load off the primary server.

Any functionality that we knew that it only needed read-only access then we could connect to the availability group and add into the connection string `ApplicationIntent=READONLY` which means that we're using the read-only replica rather than the primary, leaving the primary for regular transactions. (IIRC, by default the primary will accept any read/write connection, so you have to configure the primary not to accept read-only connections)

Anyway, the kicking off point for reading up about this is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The latest [Windows 10 1903 upgrade](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-windows-10-sandbox-safely-test-apps/) already has inbuilt Sandbox features, where you can run SQL server within it's own sandbox. I don't think SQL Server itself has its own inbuilt sandbox environment, as it would be practically impossible to manage within a normal Windows server that is not using sandbox, if you know what I mean.